# Does Android Studio have similar function to xcode's autolayout?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, autolayout

I'm a beginner iOS developer but is interested in learning Android development. In Xcode, the autolayout is especially helpful when it comes to layout in different rotations, e.g. landscape vs portrait. I was just wondering if Android Studio has a similar function? if not, how does android deal with layout in different size class?

Comment: Android has supported different orientations and "size classes" like this since the very beginning

Comment: @biddulph.r thank you very much for the comment. So for example, if I come up with a user interface in portrait in android studio, when I'm testing it, and rotate the device to landscape, android will automatically recalculate and display the new layout, according to the constriants I set in portrait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes most probely it is like new Constraint layout.

> More info[from doc]: Constraint Layout: This new layout is a flexible layout
>   manager for your app that allows you to create dynamic user interfaces
>   without nesting multiple layouts. It is distributed as a support
>   library that is tightly coupled with Android Studio and backwards
>   compatible to API Level 9.

Link: [constraint-layout](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

[image: This is the screenshot of constraint layout which is same as ios]

**Note: For this you have to use Android Studio 2.2 preview**

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out!!

Comment: @TonyStark , Even i'm happy to help iron men ;) btw yr welcom